# Insert into map with pair as key and list as value

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

I have the following map in C++:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> iPair;

std::map< iPair, std::list< iPair > > world;
```

I want to make insert and update of the map for a pair(u,v) -> push back in list:

```
 iPair src = make_pair(p1, u1);
 iPair dst = make_pair(p2, u2);
 map[src].push_back(dst);
```

I get a compiling error when trying to access `map[src]`:

> error: missing template arguments before ‘[’ token

Comment: Not `map[src]`, but `world[src]` - that's the name of your variable, isn't it?

Comment: Chances are you have `using namespace std;` which is causing your use of `map` to be resolved to `std::map` which requires a template parameter like the error says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `world[src]` since that is the name of your map variable, that should work.